Formalising a specific coordinate transformation
Suppose I have a PDE given as follows,
$$\left\{\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} + \left(\frac{2}{r} + \frac{f'}{f}\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial r} - \frac{1}{f^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\right\}u(r,t) = 0~, \tag{1}$$
where I have the function $f\equiv f(r)$ in the above PDE. I want to solve the restricted PDE where the variables $r,t$ are not independent but constrained in a manner. That is, suppose I define a variable $X = r - f^{-2}t$. I want to solve for functions $v(X)$ that may satisfy $(1)$, if they exist at all.
Since the problem now reduces to an ODE, I expect I can use the chain rule:
$$\frac{d}{dX} = \frac{\partial r}{\partial X}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial t}{\partial X}\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \tag{2}~.$$
But now I am not sure how to compute the coefficients $\partial r/\partial X$ and so on, since I am not sure how to invert the transformation in the right way. I've done this before where I've replaced $r,t$ with a different set of two independent variables. But now I'm not sure how to do this (or if this can be done) in this restricted case where $r,t$ are no longer independent.

Crossposted from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/825525/2451

And now migrated https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4962147/formalising-a-specific-coordinate-transformation
